# How to leave a Google Shared Drive that I'm not editor

Tags: google-drive, spam-prevention

Today I opened my Google Drive and a *Shared Drive* with the name **### Get a $1,000 Per Month** appeared. This drive has only one file in it, a Google Slides presentation named **Get a $1,000 Per Month**.

Since I'm not owner or editor of this shared drive, I can't find a way to leave or remove it. Shared settings for the file in the folder is greyed out.

Anyone knows how to get rid of this?

Bellow are some screen captures showing what is happening:
[image: Unwanted shared drive]

This is the Shared Drive settings page. See that I don't have any permissions to change these settings.
[image]

I also contacted Google support through their chat but they did not find a way to remove this shared folder from my account

Answer (score 2):

I know you posted this a year ago, but I just had this issue and think I found a solution.  I had to go to Google Groups (groups.google.com), choose the group that was making me be in the shared drive, and leave it.